What's wrong with BIP32 from NIST's perspective?
BIP32 is listed as Non-Approved Security Functions (see page 29 in 1). I could not find any problem with the primitives used in BIP32.
HMAC-SHA512: This is a FIPS-approved algorithm (see page 25 in 1).
secp256k1:

This curve is allowed to be used for blockchain-related applications (see page 12 in 2).

Moreover, SLIP10, which is the generalization of BIP32, is on the Non-FIPS Approved list even though it supports the NIST P-256 curve (See 3 and
SLIP10)

It could be that if NIST analyzed it, there might be nothing wrong with BIP32.  However, FIPS 140 is all about general encryption related algorithms and BIP32 seems rather Bitcoin specific so I doubt that NIST ever would standardize it.  Perhaps if BIP32 were to be used in a different context that was important to the US government then NIST might take a look at standardizing it.

So why can't BIP32 be used in fips mode on these devices? BIP32 already consists of a few NIST-approved algorithms.

Do we really need a seperate NIST standard for BIP32 to include it in FIPS mode?

FIPS 140-2 is a process in which someone needs to prepare all the documents etc. AFAIK, the Bitcoin is already left the Bip-32...

"So why can't BIP32 be used in fips mode on these devices?"  It could be if it was in the security policy of the crypto module.
